# How to print ($(this)) in jquery ,as var_dump is used in php

Tags: jquery

I am  new to jquery i want to know .

How to print `($(this))` in jquery ,as `var_dump`  is used in php

Comment: look up `console.log`, you want to do the js debugging in the console, not on screen.

Comment: Are you trying to debug javascript variables?  If so, write to the console or alert it

Comment: what should i write in alert . alert($(this))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even more comfortable than var_dump, as you can inspect the collection and all attributes neatly arranged in the console:

```
console.log($(this));
```

Comment: Thanks ,I was trying to get what is in  $(this)[0].files

Comment: Errm... then just do console.log($(this)[0].files); ? o.O

Comment: You're welcome - please select my answer as valid if it was helpful.